# C++: Extracting parameter type from static function in struct

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, template-meta-programming, template-argument-deduction

Say I have something like this:

```
template<typename T, typename R>
struct MyStruct {
    static R myfunc(T);
};

struct MyStructInst: S<int, double> {
    static double myfunc(int i) { return i; }
};
```

Then later, I have a template that takes `M`, a type that I will assume has a static `myfunc` function with one parameter (e.g. `MyStructInst`). I want to extract the parameter type and the result type of `myfunc`:

```
template<typename M,
    typename ParamType = ???,
    typename ResultType = decltype(declval(M::myfunc))> // I think this works?
struct MyStruct2 {
    ...
};
```

What's the easiest way to get `ParamType`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about

```
template <typename R, typename A0, typename ... As>
constexpr A0 firstArg (R(*)(A0, As...));

template <typename M,
          typename PT = decltype(firstArg(&M::myfunc)),
          typename RT = decltype(M::myfunc(std::declval<PT>()))>
struct MyStruct2 
 { };
```

?

I mean... if you declare (there is no needs to implement it because is used only inside a `decltype()`, so only the returned type is important) a function that receive a function type (i remember that a pointer to a **static** method is like a pointer to a traditional function) that receive one or more arguments and return the type of the first argument

```
template <typename R, typename A0, typename ... As>
constexpr A0 firstArg (R(*)(A0, As...));
```

given a template typename `M`, you can obtain the first parameter of the `myFunc()` method (if any) with

```
typename PT = decltype(firstArg(&M::myfunc))
```

Given `PT` (the type of the first type parameter) you can obtain the returned type simply simulating (inside `decltype()`, using `std::declval()`) a call to `myfunc()` with a object of type `PT`

```
typename RT = decltype(M::myfunc(std::declval<PT>()))
```

The following is a full compiling example

```
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T, typename R>
struct MyStruct
 { static R myfunc(T); };

struct MyStructInst 
 { static double myfunc(int i) { return i; } };

template <typename R, typename A0, typename ... As>
constexpr A0 firstArg (R(*)(A0, As...));

template <typename M,
          typename PT = decltype(firstArg(&M::myfunc)),
          typename RT = decltype(M::myfunc(std::declval<PT>()))>
struct MyStruct2 
 { using type1 = PT; using type2 = RT; };

int main ()
 {
   static_assert( std::is_same<int,
      typename MyStruct2<MyStructInst>::type1>{}, "!");
   static_assert( std::is_same<double,
      typename MyStruct2<MyStructInst>::type2>{}, "!");
   static_assert( std::is_same<long,
      typename MyStruct2<MyStruct<long, std::string>>::type1>{}, "!");
   static_assert( std::is_same<std::string,
      typename MyStruct2<MyStruct<long, std::string>>::type2>{}, "!");
 }
```